# PHP array_push with key => value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code

```
foreach ($query1 as $post)
{
    foreach ($query2 as $data)
    {
        if ($post->post_id == $data->post_id)
        {
            // add all actions from a post to its array
            if (!isset($post->post_meta))
            {
                $post->post_meta = array( strtolower($data->post_meta_key) => $data->post_meta_value );
            }
            else
            {
                array_push( $post->post_meta[strtolower($data->post_meta_key)] = $data->post_meta_value );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure how to fix the code. Im not getting the value, only the key, and a few errors.

> array_push() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

It should print out something like this

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 218
            [post_meta] => Array
                (
                    [flagged] => 0
                    [deleted] => 1
                )

        )
```

Comment: what returned $data->post_meta_value ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php PHP has a good documentation, use it when in trouble.

Comment: Unclear what parts of the code do. You test if `$post->post_meta` is set, but you are certain that `$post->post_meta[strtolower($data->post_meta_key)]` is set?

Comment: @lucasmus - Yes, im positive post_meta_key is set... I update the code a question a little. I changed the code. Im new with PHP, but does it have what to do with the object and than array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$post->post_meta[strtolower($data->post_meta_key)] = $data->post_meta_value;
```

Comment: @cnot Can you clarify that with an exact error message, please?

Comment: array_push() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @cnot Right, and I'm saying you should not use `array_push` but just assign the value to the key. `array_push` doesn't do keys.

Comment: ...I feel like a dumb@ss... I dont know why i didnt do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think, you need this:

```
 $post->post_meta[strtolower($data->post_meta_key)] = $data->post_meta_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page of `array_push`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) (emphasis mine):

> `array_push()` treats array as a [**stack**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29), and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array.

So you cannot pass a key. If you want to pass a key, use

```
$yourArray[$theKey] = $theValue;
```

which will then either overwrite the `$theValue` for `$theKey` if it already exists or append it to the end of the array. Also see:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others. Besides, as php manual note:

**Note:** If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php